# Test Grails app with daemon option

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

I’m using Grails version 2.3 RC2.

When running `grails> test-app Something`, Grails says “running without daemon”.

How can I run test-app with a daemon (if it really has this option)?

Comment: Are you working on Windows OS? Daemon is "disabled" for windows in interactive mode. If OS other than windows is used then, you can set `grails.project.fork` for test to have a property as `daemon:true` in `BuildConfig`.

Comment: yes, win xp exactly. thanks a lot for the help, cheers.

Comment: Why is daemon disabled for windows? Is there a way to activate it?